# Joomla 3->4 upgrade, page works OK but not as a cron job

Tags: joomla-4

I've got a few php pages which after upgrading to Joomla 4 didn't work, I have managed to get them working properly if I manually open them in the browser but they fail when run as a cron job.

I am using PHP 8.0

I am sure I must be missing something simple and hope that someone can give me some pointers.

I've only included the first part of the code which contains the Joomla references as Stackoverflow didn't like all the code included

```
$length_to_fetch_minutes = 10;


define('_JEXEC', 1);

define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// instantiate application
// $app   = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Set the application as global app
// \Joomla\CMS\Factory::$application = $app;

// $app->createExtensionNamespaceMap();

// Boot the DI container
$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();

$container->alias('session.web', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('session', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('JSession', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');

// Instantiate the application.
$app = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);

// Set the application as global app
\Joomla\CMS\Factory::$application = $app;


// database connection
$dbj     = JFactory::getDbo();

JLoader::discover('Sim', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/sim');
```

The error is:

> Blockquote RuntimeException {#168
> #message: "Could not parse the requested URI http:///home/ruralde1/example.com/iot2/data.php"
> #code: 0
> #file: "./example.com/iot2/libraries/vendor/joomla/uri/src/AbstractUri.php"
> #line: 373
> trace: {
> ./example.com/iot2/libraries/vendor/joomla/uri/src/AbstractUri.php:373 { â€¦}
> ./example.com/iot2/libraries/src/Uri/Uri.php:290 {
> Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri->parse($uri)
> â€º {
> â€º     return parent::parse($uri);
> â€º }
> arguments: {
> $uri: "http:///home/ruralde1/example.com/iot2/data.php"
> }
> }

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your error message is there is an extra forward slash after the `http:`.

```
$uri: "http:///home/ruralde1/example.com/iot2/data.php" } }
```

I would say that you need to investigate what creates that $uri string.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution and has nothing to do with Joomla; problem > Server Environment of PATH of execution. As for now I solved it by CD into the directory and run the script from there